# open an activity with a button in fragment

Tags: android

I've solved the problem by setting onclick in xml. Thanks to you all anyway.

I am trying to open an activity with a button in a fragment. But it doesn't seem working with the codes I've been searched online.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.view2, container, false);
}
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    button = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.sys_file);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "success2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), system_file_visit_control.class));
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: What happens when you click the button?

Comment: R you sure system_file_visit_control.class is a activity???

Comment: Nothing happens with the click.@IvanWooll

Comment: Yes@miladsalimi

Answer (score 1):

Try to move this code to `onViewCreated` method.

Like this:

```
 @Override
 public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.sys_file);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "success2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            getContext().startActivity(new Intent(getContext(), system_file_visit_control.class));
        }

    });
}
```

If `system_file_visit_control` is an Activity then this will move to this activity after pressing the button.

Comment: The toast message is shown by pressing the button ?

Answer (score 0):

It might help you, Replace your code with this

```
private View v;
private Context mContext;

@Override
public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    mContext = context;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test, container, false);
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    button = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.sys_file);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "success2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            startActivity(new Intent(mContext, system_file_visit_control.class));
        }

    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify onCreateView by

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view2, container, false);
    button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.sys_file);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Start your activity
        }
    });
    return rootView;
}
```